# Removing Lysol from oven

Tags: experimental-chemistry, cleaning

My son put Lysol in the oven, how do I make it safe again? I really don't want to blow up my house over a chicken pot pie. I have new recipe that I really want to try out and it does not include bleach, or Lysol.

Comment: Lysol uses lots of different mixtures for their cleaning products. Does this product list the active ingredients?

Comment: Have a self cleaning oven? // Running that would burn up pretty much any organic compounds. Then wipe oven out with a damp cloth.

Comment: Wipe the oven down with water and let that dry. If you have an oven that has a circulation fan, turn just the fan on and let that run for a few minutes. If you want to run the self cleaning cycle after that, you should be fine to do so. The reason I suggest the wipe down first is so you don't have a lot of residual chemicals that can lead to an atmosphere that can support a fire (being above the LEL).